# Use generated argument array/string in find

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to pass a generated argument array (or string) to a find command in bash, but everything I tried doesn't work. It seems to be something with the quoting, but I don't know how to solve this.

Here is what I tried.

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/path/to/folders/"
excludes=()
excludes+=(" -not -path \"./cache/*\"")
excludes+=(" -not -path \"./tmp/*\"")
find $path -type f \( "${excludes[@]}" \) >test.txt
```

I just get this message `find: Der Pfad muß vor dem Suchkriterium stehen:  -not -path "./cache/*"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to quote multiple arguments, try:

```
path="/path/to/folders/"
excludes=( -not -path "./cache/*" -not -path "./tmp/*" )
find "$path" -type f \( "${excludes[@]}" \) >test.txt
```

Comment: More precisely, he *must not* quote multiple arguments in a manner that combines them into fewer arguments.  Doing so is the essential problem of his attempt.  He can still build his `excludes` array in multiple steps, though.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant by `multiple arguments`, doing that in multiple steps using `+=` is not a problem.